# Require Password to Change User Information using Sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have a simple user model with an edit page. Currently you can change your email and your password (with a password confirmation) but I don't currently require you to type your password again before changing any of that information.

I have a before filter that requires you to be logged in as well as a before filter to ensure you can only edit your own profile. However, in the case of public computers, I would like to re-authenticate a user by making them type their password.

I am using [sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) to back my authentication. How would I go about doing this. I don't see any methods for checking the password after being logged in. Below is my current users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :require_login, :only => [ :edit, :update ]
  before_filter :correct_user, :only => [ :edit, :update ]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
      login_user(@user)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

  private

  def correct_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user == @user
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

I've opened an issue on Sorcery's github page. It sounds like the creator will be opening a method called validate_credentials() in the future.

Source: https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/issues/34#issuecomment-2108845